# Why does this Jinja macro render text instead of HTML?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have the following template called `post-macro`, but when I call the macro in the `page.html` template, it inserts a string, with quotes, containing the HTML, rather than directly inserting the HTML.

`post-macro`:

```
{% macro postmacro(post) %}
// html here
{% endmacro %}
```

`page.html`:

```
{% from "post-macro" import postmacro with context %}
{{ postmacro(post) }}
```

It renders the page like this.  Notice the double quotes around the output.

```
"
    html here
"
```

What do I need to change to get the HTML directly rather than in quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename the `post-macro` template to `post-macro.html` and Jinja will render HTML directly.