# Importing jinja macros

Tags: html, jinja2

I have a relatively simple macro which contains the layout of some otherwise extremely repetitive code.

```
{% macro build_thing(var1, var2, var3) %} 
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <a href="{{ var1 }}"></a>
    <div class="caption">
      <h4>{{ var2 }}</h4>
      <p class="text-muted">{{ var3 }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

The actual macro is a bit lengthier but essentially very similar. If I put the code directly into the template where I use it (say home.html), and call it with

```
{{ build_thing("genericClass", "Lorem Ipsum", "More Filler") }}
```

then the page renders perfectly and there are no issues. However, if I put the code into another template file (say macros.jinja) and try to import the macro through

```
{% from "macros.jinja" import build_thing %}
```

It renders the page, but puts quotes around the entire macro so *all the code becomes plain text* and not html. I've tried searching for a solution here on stack overflow but I couldn't find a similar issue. Also, the [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#macros) for macro's wasn't very helpful in providing any insight either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your file has the extension `jina` it needs to be `html` so that jinja recognizes this as html and does not escape it.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597537/why-does-this-jinja-macro-render-text-instead-of-html) for details